# Check if user is already logged in and skip if it is true

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am creating web scraping code to login to website and input some data. There is login form before getting to the actual page. My code works there is login first. However website does not ask to login in if you have already logged in. Is there any way to check if login is needed or not?

Here is my code:

```
Sub ChechAutomate()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, url As String, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data")

    url = "https://infra.com/"

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 url

        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .Document
            .querySelector("[name=userName]").Value = "username"
            .querySelector("[name=password]").Value = "password123"
            .querySelector("[type=submit]").Click

            'While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            .querySelector("[id=companySearchKeyData]").Value = ws.Range("T24").Value
            .querySelector("[type=submit]").Click
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It would depend on the website, but I know a lot of web applications have a bit of text in the top-right that says "login" or something similar, but then if you are logged in it says something different like "my account". You could just scrape that area first to see whether login is needed or not.

Comment: There is `id="login-bis-id-btn"` present on login page and not on others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest check is to use `querySelectorAll` to return a nodeList and check its length IMO. Inside the `With .document` ...

```
If .querySelectorAll("#login-bis-id-btn").length > 0 Then
    'present ....do login page stuff
Else
    'do other stuff
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a conditional statement to check which page you are on. In that case the following logic might help:

```
Sub ChechAutomate()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, url As String, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument, idCheck As Object

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data")

    url = "https://infra.com/"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 url
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .document
    End With

    Set idCheck = Html.querySelector("#login-bis-id-btn")
    If Not idCheck Is Nothing Then
        Html.querySelector("[name=userName]").Value = "username"
        Html.querySelector("[name=password]").Value = "password123"
        Html.querySelector("[type=submit]").Click
        While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Else:
        Debug.Print "You are already logged-in"
    End If

    'I don't know the role of the following two lines, though

    Html.querySelector("[id=companySearchKeyData]").Value = ws.Range("T24").Value
    Html.querySelector("[type=submit]").Click
End Sub
```

Comment: Also nice way to frame +