# Skip login page, if already logged-in

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

If Internet Explorer starts for the first time with code then there is no problem.

If the web site is already logged in the system, I get an error

> Object does not support...

I want to skip this login stage if the webpage is already logged-in.

The sample code I used

```vb
Sub Login()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, url As String
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument, idCheck As Object

    url = "https://abc-site.com/"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 url
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .document
    End With

    Set idCheck = Html.querySelector(".Log In")
    If Not idCheck Is Nothing Then
        Html.querySelector("[name=userName]").Value = "username"
        Html.querySelector("[name=password]").Value = "password"
        Html.querySelector("[type=submit]").Click
        While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

```html
USER NAME
<input id="Content1_UserIDView_txtUserid_UiInput" ng-class="{'error' : AuthMethod.error}" type="text" class="form-control bb-input bb-username-input ng-pristine ng-scope ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" placeholder="User ID" autocomplete="off" ng-model="AuthMethod.user" ng-change="AuthMethod.getMethodOnChange(method.input.id)" ng-disabled="false" ng-if="method.label.text !== ' *' &amp;&amp; method.input.id.length > 0" ng-init="AuthMethod.getUser()" tabindex="0" focus-if="" required="" aria-invalid="true">

PASSWORD
<input id="Content_UserIDView_tbxPassword_UiInput" ng-class="{'error' : AuthMethod.error}" type="password" class="form-control bb-input bb-password-input ng-pristine ng-scope ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" ng-model="AuthMethod.pass" ng-change="AuthMethod.getPassOnChange(method.input.id, $event)" ng-disabled="false" ng-if="method.label.text !== ' *' &amp;&amp; method.input.id.length > 0" ng-init="AuthMethod.getPass()" tabindex="0" focus-if="AuthMethod.authMethodId[0].label.text.length === 0" required="" aria-invalid="true">

Login Button
<a href="#" class="btn-primary bb-binding" ng-disabled="UserIdButton.shouldDisableButton()" ng-click="!UserIdButton.shouldDisableButton() &amp;&amp; UserIdButton.click(UserIdButton.userIdViewBtn.button.id)" title=" Log In" disabled="disabled">
                 Log In
        </a>
```

Comment: I tried to test your code, and browsed the url address in the code, I found that the page does not have an option to log in, so I am not sure how you encountered this problem. On which line of the code does the problem occur? What is the detailed error message?

Comment: I just gave example link in url section, unfortunately that site is existing... sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Well, how do you record the user's login status? Session or something else? Or you can use a hidden domain to store the username and use it to determine whether to skip the login operation.

Comment: @XudongPeng, As once we log in to the site, it automatically stores username and password for while till you log out of your session. In case if I forgot to logout then the session will be in login status till I log out. In this case if i start the macro again, then that particular site will no more ask for credentials since that is already in login status. In this scenario i need to skip the log in code and move on to next line of code..

Comment: Team, can anyone help me out on this.. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what the homepage of the website looks like, but I think it should not contain a login form. So in the code you give, as long as it cannot find the login form element `If Not idCheck Is Nothing Then`, it skips the login operation. On which line of the code is your current problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution for the above query from the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56328773/check-if-user-is-already-logged-in-and-skip-if-it-is-true/56329529)

```
If .querySelectorAll("#Content1_UserIDView_txtUserid_UiInput").length > 0 Then
    'do login page stuff
Else
    'Skip login code
End If
    'proceed with the other code....
```

Thanks QHarr it helped me and resolved my problem.